# Prime 95 Cpuz Speed Fan

Tags: overclocking

Hi I am looking for a Linux version of Prime95 CpuZ and Speed Fan also Haven Direct X is there a Linux version of these programs I want to over clock my computer and I do not like Windows I want to over clock on Linux

Comment: This looks more like a question for http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/...

Answer (score 0):

Official Linux version of P95: http://www.mersenne.org/ftp_root/gimps/p95v289.linux64.tar.gz

Once downloaded, unpack it and run `./mprime -m`

---

Temperature monitoring program: Psensor

To install Psesnor, you'll need to open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install psensor
```

---

To get the information that CPU-Z provides, just run this command:

```
lscpu
```